# iOS Maintain State of a UITableViewCell Custom Button & View in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a button (+) on a tableviewcell when I tap on the button it is hidden and another view is revealed that contains quantity selector button (- Qty 1 +). I am uncertain how to maintain the state of the buttons, view, and label when the cell scrolls away and returns.

The cells are all in different tableview sections.

Comment: Keep the state of the cell in the model.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight could you elaborate? When I import the data from JSON, I create objects that I put into an array for the tableview's data source. Do you recommend that I update the data source with the cell's state?